# .jspx files not getting compiled correctly in weblogic application server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles, weblogic12c

I have created a Spring MVC based application and have used TilesViewResolver as my View resolver. I have configured tiles-definition in layout.xml file and views definition in  views.xml file. Correctly configured this in webmvc-config.xml file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
          <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
            <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
          </list>
        </property>
  </bean>
```

Everything works fine on apache tomcat 6 server and my page is correctly displayed. But my page is not at all displayed when I deploy the same application in Weblogic 12 c server. I could only see the source of the page (from browser), which is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM  "about:legacy-compat">
<html xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
      <spring:theme code="styleSheet" var="roo_css" />
      <spring:url value="/" var="roo_css_url" />
      <spring:url value="/resources/dojo/dojo.js" var="dojo_url" />
      <spring:url value="/resources/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" var="tundra_url" />
      <spring:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" var="spring_url" />
      <spring:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" var="spring_dojo_url" />
      <spring:url value="/resources/images/favicon.ico" var="favicon" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="" />
      <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="" />
      <script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: false, isDebug: false, locale: 'en-us'};</script>
      <script src="" type="text/javascript" />
      <script src="" type="text/javascript" />
      <script src="" type="text/javascript" />
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser");</script>
      <spring:message code="application_name" var="app_name" htmlEscape="false" />
      <title>
         <spring:message code="welcome_h3" arguments="" />
      </title>
   </head>
   <body class="tundra spring">
      <div id="wrapper">
         <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" ignore="true" />
         <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" ignore="true" />
         <div id="main">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" ignore="true" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Maven dependency for apache tiles jar is already there :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

It seems that Weblogic server was unable to process the tiles (tiles TLD visible in the source). There is no exception in server logs or console.

What extra do i need to do for this to work on Weblogic server.

**EDIT**

I noticed that the source shown on the browser is from my jspx files, which I have created for Tiles. Somehow, the .jspx files are not getting compiled correctly in weblogic 12c server, whereas it works file in tomcat 6 server.

Also, this happens only when I deploy my application in server which is added in the eclipse. When I deploy the same application in a standalone server (same instance, same domain) it works fine. Is it something to do with the weblogic server settings inside eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

I don't  know the Spring MVC Tiles plugin but in tradiitonal JSPs you have to declare the Tag library adding this line on top of your JSP files:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
```

If you don't have network access you can use a local reference adding to your web.xml file reference:

```
<taglib>
 <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tiles.tld</taglib-uri>
 <taglib-location>[YOUR TLD PATH, /WEB-INF/tld/tiles.tld]</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

In this case the declaration must be:

Comment: Not a solution, the application works fine in tomcat 6 server, but not on weblogic. That means all the basic configurations are already done.